# Karate - Unable to get Objects from json array

Tags: karate

I am trying to get json objects from a json array as a list. Below is my json sample, I am generating from a js function dynamically and storing it in id json variable.

```
[{
"id": "0f0ae12842ab4870a76f082a67236469",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "43894"
},
{
"id": "0c19b022242b4a27ab1b47a46605a9ca",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "19b27546a77f4210bd5764e350515b90",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "0715c43653c94a8b8d91dcc1646c04d5",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "1ea75688810d49089b06dc787f9dc586",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
}]
   //Output: Should be list of objects outside array.
  {
"id": "0f0ae12842ab4870a76f082a67236469",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "43894"
},
{
"id": "0c19b022242b4a27ab1b47a46605a9ca",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "19b27546a77f4210bd5764e350515b90",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "0715c43653c94a8b8d91dcc1646c04d5",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
},
{
"id": "1ea75688810d49089b06dc787f9dc586",
"date": "2019-12-12T05:00:23.182Z",
"key": "93476"
}
```

I am trying with this function:
json temp = id[ * ]; // I am getting as array with list of elements which is same as above
I also tried:
json temp = get[ * ] id; // Same as above

I need this as a list of objects outside an array so that I can set to another json variable.

Comment: sorry this is so confusing. you have an array of objects. now what do you want out of it. an array of primitives ? edit your question and provide an example of what you want at the end please

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Peter, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
* def temp = id[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, if I do that I an just getting the 1st element. Is there a way where we can get all elements as list.

Comment: @varun a list IS a JSON array. I think you have some confusion about what JSON is, can you talk to someone near you who knows JSON well. please ? the moment you say "all elements" there WILL be a square bracket `[]`. does that make sense ?

Comment: That make sense Peter thanks. But, what i am trying to do is to push the elements to an existing array in json. Is there a best way you could suggest? When I use a set, it goes as an array instead I wanted to append.

Comment: @VarunPatil yes, read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms